# I want to split a string and want to put in the dropdown list in html, javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
strPropertyEvents=20 Aug 2014-New Activity 1 21 Aug 2014-gfdbfjdb 21 Aug 2014-anubhav 24 ug 2014-hjdf
```

In strPropertyEventas it is stored in the form of string but I want to split this string in such a manner that the output is in a dropdown list as

```
20 Aug 2014-New Activity 1
21 Aug 2014-gfdbfjdb 
21 Aug 2014-anubhav
24 ug 2014-hjdf
```

Please tell the code so that I can use it.

Comment: if there is no pattern in your string better to do it manually using `slice`.

Comment: Please help me , I dont know how to use slice... Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a delimiter or as mritunjay told splice but slice will be a problem for long strings. Is this a string that you are creating or getting from a remote place? If you have control over the string strPropertyEvents then add delimters like [jsbin_example](http://jsbin.com/rileki/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Then you could do this

```
<select id="list">
</select>

var strPropertyEvents='20 Aug 2014-New Activity 1###21 Aug 2014-gfdbfjdb###21 Aug 2014-anubhav###24 ug 2014-hjdf';

var strList = strPropertyEvents.split('###');
console.log(strList);
$.each(strList,function(index,val){

 $("#list").append('<option>'+val+'</option>');
});
```

Comment: ok i have  made , there but i dont know how to code it. Please could you help me

Comment: i have updated and if it is satisfactory, do accept the answer